# How to get free testnet ether

Tags: ether, testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, testing

I can't get free testnet ether. I tried already the faucet, I tried mining, it all does not work. Could someone maybe just send me some for some testing?

0x769d1Aab08dCF3F27289194896c0A41F7d51d412

Sorry for begging, but after 3 hours of testing around to find the error, I am giving up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just sent you the 2 unused ether after my testings done. Hope you got it